# How to tell if error occured in MySQL client script

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit, rollback

I can't discover how to tell if an error occurred in a MySQL client script (after a couple of hours googling and reading the MySQL docs. I would expect there would be something like an error flag or error number that gets set when an error occurs and that you could test this with something like the following:

start transaction
error_flag = false;  #just to be safe
...do some work...
... do some more work ...
if ( error_flag == true )
then
    rollback
else
    commit
;

What's the canonical was of doing this?  Am I way off base thinking this approach would work?

Thanks in advancd

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        $errm = "[SQL" . mysql_errno() . "] " . mysql_error();
        $this->rollback(); //implement your rollback
        throw new Exception($errm);
    }
```

this is the old mysql_* way. Please use pdo instead.